# How to monitor my internet traffic split between a PC and laptop?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet

I'll try to describe my problem as specific as possible.

So I have an internet connection and there are two PCs using it.
Now let's call my laptop as A and the other PC as B. 
**Laptop A** - My laptop, I pay the bill, I need sufficient speed for my work. (uses wifi ONLY)
**Desktop B** - A desktop computer, which is used for my work only but the worker uses it for downloading and stuff. I can't monitor the data through my wifi because this desktop is connected via a LAN cable (since desktop doesn't have a wifi, it uses LAN cable).

Now I'm really confused what to do ?
**My questions**
Is it possible to divide speed in ratio ? Like my laptop gets 70% and his 30%.
Is it possible to block major torrent and other video streaming websites on his desktop?
Is it possible to monitor traffic which is going via LAN cable and not Wifi ?

I'm using iBall router.

Comment: If he's not tech-savvy or doesn't have administrative privileges on the machine you can just set his Ethernet NIC's speed to 10MB/s half duplex to slow him down. Quick and dirty solution but that might be all you need, otherwise you'll most likely need to install an alternative firmware like OpenWRT if your router is compatible or buy a compatible device.

Comment: Will OpenWRT help monitor traffic via LAN cable as well ?

Comment: Yes, take a look at [their documentation](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/packet.scheduler/packet.scheduler).

Comment: You will need a router with bandwidth control/QoS capabilities, or one that supports DD-WRT or OpenWRT. I don't know if your iBall router has it; log in to the router settings and look around.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to divide speed in ratio ? Like my laptop gets 70% and
>   his 30%.

Yes, but that is dependent upon the **QoS** (Quality Of Service) setting afforded by your router. [A quick google search](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=iball%20router%20qos) indicates some iBall routers have QoS features.

> Is it possible to block major torrent and other video streaming
>   websites on his desktop?

Yes. There are a couple different ways one could go about this, such as:

- Configuring the desktop to use OpenDNS
- Blocking major sites via hosts file on the desktop
- Install parental URL filtering software like NetNanny or K9 Web Protection on the desktop

Just to name a few.

> Is it possible to monitor traffic which is going via LAN cable and not
>   Wifi ?

Yes, using the same methods above. If you want to get really technical (guessing you don't) you can sniff the traffic with a program like Wireshark. (not recommended for what you want to accomplish)